# Fixing 'reducer' Required Argument Error in Redux Saga

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, debugging, redux

I am trying to learn redux saga by following the below tutorial.
but when I include the below line I am getting an error.

Error in /turbo_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit@1.8.3/dist/redux-toolkit.cjs.development.js (525:15)
"reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers

can you let me know how to fix it
providing my code below
I installed all the packages and tried to debug but still no luck.
I have created actions and reducers too

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9czykt?file=index.tsx,pages%2FHome.tsx,pages%2FAbout.tsx,App.tsx,reducers%2Freducers.js,actions%2Factions.js,API.tsx

https://ibjects.medium.com/getting-started-with-redux-saga-tutorial-740954fc9e49

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Demo from './Demo';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import About from './pages/About';
import Products from './pages/Products';
import Error from './pages/Error';
import SharedLayout from './pages/SharedLayout';
import SingleProduct from './pages/SingleProduct';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
//import { myReducer } from '../reducers';
import createSagaMiddleware from '@redux-saga/core';
import { myReducer } from './reducers/reducers';

import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';

import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
//const store = configureStore({ reducer: myReducer });

// const store = configureStore({
//   reducer: myReducer,
//   middleware: [sagaMiddleware],
// });

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<SharedLayout />}>
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="products" element={<Products />} />
          <Route path="products/:productId" element={<SingleProduct />} />
          <Route path="login" element={<Login setUser={setUser} />} />
          <Route path="login" element={<Login setUser={setUser} />} />

          <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
      <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
        <Demo />
      </StyledEngineProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

createRoot(document.querySelector('#root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    {/* <Provider store={store}> */}
    <App />
    {/* </Provider> */}
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Looks like you initially had a typo not exporting the reducer for the store, but you've corrected that. There's a typo with the `NAME_UPDATED` action type not being declared in *that* reducer... other than this, I don't see any issue with the code you shared in the post here. Voting to close as "not reproducible or was caused by typo". Cheers.

Comment: Please note that that tutorial shows a horribly outdated style of Redux. Generally, the Redux team is recommending to use Saga only in very specific use cases (<5% of all applications), but even if you choose to use Saga, the accompanying Redux code would look very differently. This is a pre-2019 style of Redux that is about 3-5 times the amount of code of modern Redux.
Please follow the official Redux tutorial at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts first before trying to learn Saga, so you can at least assess if a tutorial is totally outdated.

Comment: @Drew thanks for your response I searched for NAME_UPDATED I found at only one place,  so I looked at the tutorial they have asked to put in action creator so I added that snippet to action creator. But still I am facing the issue. Can you update in my stackblitz so confusing. Providing updated link here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9czykt?file=components%2FStackingAreaChart.tsx,pages%2FProducts.tsx,components%2FStackOrderModified.tsx,components%2FStackOrder.tsx,components%2FWebSocketLineChart.tsx,index.tsx,actions%2FactionCreators.js

Comment: I just made `NAME_UPDATED` a string, e.g. `"NAME_UPDATED"` and your code appeared to render without issue. Like Phry said though, you are implementing older Redux patterns. I suggest just working from the current documentation.

Answer (score -1):

I see that you are not exporting the reducer from your `reducers.js` file.

[image]

Use `export` keyword before function to export.

E.g.

```
export function myReducer(state = initialState, action) {
 // your code here
}
```

Comment: I updated the above code , but still I am getting error. Can you let me know how to fix it? Providing the  sandbox link here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9czykt?file=components%2FStackingAreaChart.tsx,pages%2FProducts.tsx,components%2FStackOrderModified.tsx,components%2FStackOrder.tsx,components%2FWebSocketLineChart.tsx,index.tsx,reducers%2Freducers.js

Comment: You are using NAME_UPDATED variable but not defined it. Define this constant to resolve the error.

Comment: @phry : thanks for your response, can you let me know for what type of use cases we need to use redux-saga. This will be very helpful in implementing in my application

Comment: @Ram01 please read https://redux.js.org/usage/side-effects-approaches
In short: you should start using Saga if you have used every other tool and all of them were not enough. That almost never happens, at all. If you are learning Redux right now, you are a hundred years away from needing Saga, especially not from the start.